# HtmlAgilityPack Get all links inside a DIV

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to be able to get 2 links from inside a div.

Currently I can select one but whene there's more it doesn't seem to work.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='myclass']");

            if (node != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode type in node.SelectNodes("//a@href"))
                {
                    recipe.type += type.InnerText;
                }
            }
            else
                recipe.type = "Error fetching type.";
```

Trying to get it from this piece of HTML:

```
<div class="myclass">
<h3>Not Relevant Header</h3>
    <a href="#">This text</a>, 
    <a href="#">and this text</a>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Deejdd, You may be interested to see a much more generic solution, that can be used successfully in many more cases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='myclass']");
if(div!=null)
{
     var links = div.Descendants("a")
                    .Select(a => a.InnerText)
                    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Tested it, but for some reasen it grabs all the links outside the selected div,

Comment: Thanks a ton it worked, can't upvote you due to not having enough rep.

Answer (score 4):

Use this XPath:

```
//div[@class = 'myclass']//a
```

It grabs all descendant `a` elements in `div` with `class = 'myclass'`.

And `//a@href` is incorrect XPath.

Comment: A small question, is it possible to do this: //div[@class = 'half na']

If you don't know the exact class name to still search for it.

Comment: @Deejdd, Can you clarify? From your example you know that `@class = 'half na'`.

Comment: Let's say the class name is half name, but I only know half na.
Is it possible to still search for the div?

Comment: @Deejdd, Yep, use `contains` function, e.g.: `//div[contains(@class, 'known-part')]`

Comment: Beautiful, didn't know you could use contains in the xpath. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' myclass ')]//a
```

This selects any `a` element that is a descendant of any `div` whose `class` attribute contains a classname of `"myclass"`.

The classname may be single, or the attribute may also contain other classnames. In this case the classname may be the starting one, or the last one or may be surrounded by other classnames -- the above XPath expression correctly selects the wanted nodes in all of these different cases.

Comment: Thank you for posting, love to see the different take-ons to achieve the same result.

Comment: @Deejdd, You are welcome. Do you notice that this solution is more powerful and more applicable than the rest of the answers? It will select the wanted nodes even if tthe `class` attribute of some dives is of the form "`class="class1 myclass class2"` -- while all other answers fail to correctly select the wanted nodes in any such case.